# How can I replace 1s in one matrix with another sub matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I have a matrix-like

```
[[1, 2],
 [3, 4]]
```

and I want to replace the 1s in another matrix:

```
[[1, 0],
 [1, 1]]
```

to make this matrix:

```
[[1, 2, 0, 0],
 [3, 4, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 3, 4]]
```

The `1`s in the second matrix can be in any position, this is just an example.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`scipy.linalg.kron`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.kron.html)

```py
from scipy.linalg import kron

m1 = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
m2 = np.array([[1, 0], [1, 1]])

output:
kron(m2, m1)
array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 3, 4]])
```

### How does it work?

It takes two arrays of `M, N` and `P, Q` dimensions. Here, `m2` and `m1` with `2, 2` and `2, 2` dimensions.

Next, it multiplies the arrays in the following way:

```
m2[0,0]*m1    m2[0,1]*m1  ... m2[0,-1]*m1
m2[1,0]*m1    m2[1,1]*m1  ... m2[1,-1]*m1
        ...
m2[-1,0]*m1   m2[-1,1]*m1 ... m2[-1,-1]*m1
```

To create a single array of dimensions (`M*P`, `N*Q`)

Comment: if anyone has an explanation of how `kron` works under the hood, I would be interested :)

Comment: It's the Kronecker product. You can see it in the documentation  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.kron.html  For a definition of the Kronecker product the Wikipedia has a nice explanation  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: Noticed that numpy also have an implementation of `kron`: so `np.kron(m2,m1)` will produce the same result

Comment: @obchardon I used scipy because I actually wanted the sparse kron which is found in `scipy.sparse.kron` but just didn't include it in this example. Good to know that it is also in numpy though

Answer (score 6):

You can do that elegantly with a mathematical operation called [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) which is implemented in [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html) (or in [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.kron.html) using `numpy` underneath).

```
import numpy as np # or from scipy import linealg
a = np.array([[1, 0], 
              [1, 1]])
b = np.array([[1, 2], 
              [3, 4]])
np.kron(a, b) # or linealg.kron(a, b)
# returns
# array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
#        [3, 4, 0, 0],
#        [1, 2, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 3, 4]])
```

And here is what the Kronecker product does mathematically:

[image]

In other words, with the matrix **A** (or `numpy` array `a`) we indicate if the entries of B shall be added (if 1) or not (if 0).